# if condition in nant

Tags: nant

I am trying to figure out how to write a simple if condition in nant
that will evaluate to true when both x & y properties are true.

```
<project default="all">
    <property name="x" value="True" />
    <property name="y" value="True" />
    <target name="all">
        <echo message="x is True" if="${x}" />
        <echo message="y is True" if="${x}" />
        <echo message="x AND y are True" if="${x} AND ${y}" />
        <echo message="x AND y are True" if="${x} &amp;&amp; ${y}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

I cannot figure out the syntax for the x AND y echo message - I tried both AND and '&&' and that doesn't seem to work.(i keep getting error messages like : String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use if="${x and y}", where both x and y are in the same pair of brackets:

```
<project default="all">
    <property name="x" value="true" />
    <property name="y" value="true" />
    <target name="all">
        <echo message="x is True" if="${x}" />
        <echo message="y is True" if="${y}" />
        <echo message="x AND y are True" if="${x and y}" />

    </target>
</project>
```

Hope that helps!